# LinkedIn API - display company name of connections

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

Using the LinkedIn Javascript API I can't work out how to display the Company Name of connections.

Most of this is stock from the LinkedIN API intro

```
// This seems to be correctly getting the company data

function onLinkedInLoad() {
   IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);

   IN.API.Connections("me")
   .fields("firstName", "lastName", "industry", "positions:(company)")
   .result(displayConnections)
   .error(displayConnectionsErrors);
}
```

Here's the problem though:

```
// The Last line is wrong where I try to call the company object 
// (members[member].company)

function displayConnections(connections) {

    var connectionsDiv = document.getElementById("connections");
    var members = connections.values; // The list of members you are connected to

    for (var member in members) {
        connectionsDiv.innerHTML += "<p>" + members[member].firstName + " " +  members[member].lastName
  + " works in the " + members[member].industry + " industry at" + members[member].company;
    }     
}
```

What is the correct syntax when displaying the company fields?

Answer (score 0):

```
function onLinkedInLoad() {
  IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);

  IN.API.Connections("me")
  .fields("firstName", "lastName", "industry", "company-name")
  .result(displayConnections)
  .error(displayConnectionsErrors);
 }
```

Comment: That's still malformed as it gives a 400 error on the get request

GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(first-name,last-name,industry,company-name) 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Not really appropriate as it needs an api key and the LinkedIn auth request script etc

Answer (score 0):

I have a working example of that by doing:

```
    IN.API.Connections("me")
       .fields("firstName","lastName","pictureUrl","positions")
       .result(displayConnections)
       .error(displayProfilesErrors);
  }
```

and then accessing the positions object as follow

```
var people = connections.values;
for(var person in people)
{
   var positions = people[person].positions;
   console.log("Works at " + positions.values[0].company.name);
}
```